# Sudo or gksu for launching Sublime text 2?

Tags: sudo, sublime-text, gksu

I am new to using Ubuntu 12.04 and noticed two different ways of launching Sublime Text 2 via Terminal window, first being `sudo` and the other being `gksu`.

Upon using both I noticed it's launching different instances of Sublime Text 2 with different instances of files loaded that I've opened on both including saving snippets. Launching with `gksu` saves the snippets into `root/etc/etc` and `sudo` saves them into the `home/user/etc/etc`.

What is the preferable way to launch Sublime Text 2 in the terminal window? `sudo` or `gksu` and why?

Comment: Neither. Unless you need to edit system files, you shouldn't be running it with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Any GUI program should be elevated to root via `gksudo` or `kdesudo`.
- Any console program should be elevated using `sudo`.

Loading Sublime Text with superuser privileges **isn't a great idea**, but there's your answer.